# Send notification with delay

Tags: android, notifications

I would like to know if it is possible to send a `notification` in `android` with delay. I want that the `notification` message a few seconds (i.e. 5 seconds) later is received. The `nofication` should be created in the normal way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Text")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Open", pIntent).build();
```

I want to avoid the approach to call `Thread.sleep(5000)` before sending the `notification`, because it blocks the App.

Comment: Use handler or timer or alarm manager

Answer (score 1):

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code
    }
}, 5000);
```

This will run your code on the main thread after 5 seconds. If running on current thread is ok you can remove the `Looper.getMainLooper()`.